# ts build issue : Cannot find name 'Iterable' and many other issues

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, node-modules

I am getting tsconfig build issues, it cannot find Iterable, Iterator, Map, Set.
Although, I am using es2015,es2018 lib, this does not solve the issue, tried various fixes, such as

npm install @types/node --save-dev
npm install -g typescript@latest

Here are my package.json, tsconfig.json, tsconfig.base.json

tsconfig.json

```
  {
    "files": [

       ],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.base.json

```
    {
    "compilerOptions": {
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "composite": false,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./scripts/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "es2020",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "lib": [
        "es2018",
        "ES2015.Iterable",
        "dom"
    ]
  },
}
```

tsconfig.app.json

```
{

  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [],
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts",
  ],
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.d.ts",
  ],

}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "spa",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/localize": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/material": "~10.2.0-next.0-sha-25ce323fb",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.14",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "tsd": "^0.13.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.67",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: SInce this is tagged with angular and node-modules, I would suggest deleting the entire node_modules folder and running `install` to see if it resolves the errors.

Comment: No luck doing so :/

Comment: try installing npm install --save-dev @types/core-js

Comment: it is the same, did not fix the issue.